# Using Google Cloud SQL with App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I've searched through the suggested topics to find the answer to this question, but I got nothing.

I'm doing a project at school which I would really like if I could get up and running with Cloud SQL and AppEngine.

I'm on the "Using Google Cloud SQL with App Engine" at the moment, and it's stated in that guide that your SQL must be located in the same region (Eu/US) as your AppEngine application. I've looked thru every option in the Application dashboard, but can't find anything that says where I'm located.

Does anyone know how to fix this, or do I have to "try and fail"?

Answer (score 8):

Unless you are a paid application user your datacentre will be in the US.

[location data](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/premier/location)

> An application can run in the United States or in the European Union. If you have an App Engine Premier Account, you choose where the application runs when you create it in the Administration Console. (If you don't have a Premier Account, then your application runs in the default location, the United States.) You can't change the location after you create the application.